# doubleclick js init in a callback function

Tags: javascript, double-click

I want to pass custom targeting attributes to doubleclick (DFP) JavaScript initialization. This is simple enough when you want to do it in a static page. See link below for DFP tagging.

However, I want it set custom attributes in a callback function after a jsonp call. Is this possible? If yes, how should I go about it?

[What tags do I need to run DFP Small Business on my site?](http://www.google.com/support/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?answer=112649)